# sometimes Select / sometimes Position is faster

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, pattern-matching, filtering

As you see,

For list `L`,
`L1`(Select method) is slower than `L2`(Position method).

But for list `M`,
`M1`(Select method) is faster than `M2`(Position method).

**What makes the difference?**

```
In[1]:= L = RandomInteger[100000, 1000000];

In[2]:= L1 = Select[Range[Length[L]], L[[#]] > 555555 &]; // Timing

Out[2]= {0.984375, Null}

In[3]:= L2 = Position[L, x_ /; x > 555555, {1}]; // Timing

Out[3]= {0.359375, Null}

In[4]:= M = Table[ConstantArray[1, RandomInteger[1000]], 100000];

In[5]:= M1 = 
   Select[Range[Length[M]], Length[M[[#]]] > 555 &]; // Timing

Out[5]= {0.125, Null}

In[6]:= M2 = Position[M, x_ /; Length[x] > 555, {1}]; // Timing

Out[6]= {0.53125, Null}
```

You can see it as a screenshot also :

[image]

Comment: btw, it is better to use [RepeatedTiming](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html)  instead of Timing.

Comment: Thank you, I tried `RepeatedTiming` and the result is similar.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is faster in the first case: ``Pick[Range[Length[L]], Thread[L > 555555]] // RepeatedTiming``

Comment: And, this is faster in the second case: ``Pick[Range[Length[M]], Thread[Length /@ M > 555]]; // RepeatedTiming``

Comment: My guess is that in the first select, time is being spend extracting the index (perhaps of a packed array)  and Position is internally optimized to do this and the pattern selection is trivial.  In the second case, the pattern selection is doing more work--and the array is probably unpacked.